# What Does "Cannot modify header information?" Mean

Tags: theme-development, errors

I have come across a rather concerning issue with my theme that continues to crash my site whenever I enter a new post. I turned on debugging and I'm given the following errors messages:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-loveday/wp-content/themes/loveday/functions.php:3
```

As well as

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-loveday/wp-content/themes/loveday/functions.php:3) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-loveday/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1171
```

I probably didn't need to include the localhost info, but you can never be too sure.

I'm really confused about this as it appears that the errors are coming from WordPress specific components.

I'm still pretty new to the WordPress platform, and these errors are making my life hell at the moment. I have also noticed that none of my media assets are showing up in Media Library.

Any help or advice on what the hell is happening here will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Stu :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look up before posting your questions ! There is a detailed answer available.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: I actually found that I was declaring too many empty PHP opening blocks at the top of a couple of files.

Comment: That wont cause any issue as long as there is no white-space after <?php ?> closing tag !